# Thermodynamics: efficiency of a heat engine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, work, heat-engine

How can we calculate efficiency of a real heat engine? Do we have to consider volume of an object while calculating efficiency?

[image] Like in this question

If so, how we have to proceed?
Thanks in advance

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are talking about *maximum* amount of work, so you still consider an ideal (Carnot) cycle. But the efficiency is changing as the tank cools down, so there is an absolute maximum amount of work that can be extracted from this heat engine.

Efficiency of Carnot engine is $\eta=1-\frac{T_{min}}{T_{max}}$, and is defined as work over heat transferred at the hot end: $\eta=\frac{W}{Q_{hot}}$.

Now you have to consider this in small steps (with current temperature of the tank marked with $T$), so:
$$dW=(1-\frac{T_{min}}{T})dQ=-(1-\frac{T_{min}}{T})mc\,dT$$
Integrate and you're done.